# Unpack array of objects into strings to display on a template in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection that has within it an object that holds an array of yet more objects that need to be unpacked to display in a template eventually.

The item in the sub-object is an order, and the order contains an array of line items.

I can get the order out fine, and see the array of line items no problem, but that's where I come unstuck.

I thought the following would work (using js to convert them into an array of strings to then display somehow)

```
Template.editEvent.helpers({
    lineItems: function(req) {
        var order = req.order;
        console.log(order);
        var lines;
        var count = 1;

        _.each(order, function(item) {
            var string;
            string +count++ + '. ';
            if(item.age) { // we have a cloathing string
                string += item.age + " " + item.sex + " " + item.Season + " " + "Number: " + item.Number;
                lines.push(string);
            }
            else if(item.pushers) {
                string += "Pushers needed: " + item.pushers;
                lines.push(string);
            }
            else if(item.cots) {
                string += "Cots needed: " + item.pushers;
                lines.push(string); 
            }
            else if(items.extra) {
                string = "Extra info: " + item.extra;
                lines.push(string);
            }   
            else {
                string = "Don't know this field";
                lines.push(string);
            }
            console.log(lines);
        });
        return lines;
    }
})
```

Where the tests are to see if the line item starts with the field shown (because the line items can be different).

However, the _.each is throwing up on the client, (it works fine in the startup code, so I guess from that its server only?)

Am I barking up the wrong tree here, should this embedded object be a new collection? If I am right, how do I go about displaying the returned string array (only just thought of this) in the template anway?

Comment: you are not initializing `lines`. use `var lines = []`; also, what is: `string +count++ + '. '`? did you mean `string += count++ + '. '`? If so then you also need to initialize `string` (e.g., `= ""`).

Comment: Christian, please make this an answer so that I can accept it. Your fantastic.  One last question. I now have an array of strings.. how do I display them one to a line in the template?? Not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `lines`. Use:

```
var lines = [];
```

also, what is: `string +count++ + '. '`? did you mean `string += count++ + '. '`? If so then you also need to initialize string, e.g., `var string = "";`

From your comment, I get the sense that what you really want is to show the list reactively in the template. For that, you'd probably want to directly use a transform. Here is how that could work. Alternatively you could wrap your code into a `Deps.autorun`.

HTML (e.g., `edit_event.html`):

```html
<template name="editEvent">
    {{lines}}
</template>
```

Javascript (e.g., `edit_event.js`):

```
Template.editEvent.lines = function() {
    var order = Orders.find(
        {id: Session.get('currentOrder')}, 
        {limit: 1,
         transform: function(order) {
             console.log(order);
             var lines;
             var count = 1;

             _.each(order, function(item) {
                 var string = count++ + '. ';
                 if(item.age) { // we have a cloathing string
                     string += item.age + " " + item.sex + " " 
                         + item.Season + " " + "Number: " + item.Number;
                     lines.push(string);
                 }
                 else if(item.pushers) {
                     string += "Pushers needed: " + item.pushers;
                     lines.push(string);
                 }
                 else if(item.cots) {
                     string += "Cots needed: " + item.pushers;
                     lines.push(string); 
                 }
                 else if(items.extra) {
                     string = "Extra info: " + item.extra;
                     lines.push(string);
                 }   
                 else {
                     string = "Don't know this field";
                     lines.push(string);
                 }
                 console.log(lines);
             });
             return lines;
         }
        })
}
```

Comment: This is an awsome answer, thanks. Got one issues still though, what I'm getting in {{lines}} in an array of strings, which, I guess as would be expected prints one sting concatenated straight onto the end of the next. Is there a way I can get at the strings individually in the array using an #each or something so that I can put them on a line each with a checkbox or some other control at the end of it?